# How should I call the 'moving target' problem?

Tags: terminology

I have a problem with Swype. Every time I finish a phrase and try to hit the [Send] button, I discover that it's moved. This happens because the word suggestion bar disappears after writing the dot.

I've called this the '[moving target problem](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?6519-Eliminate-the-moving-target-problem)'. Is this term correct?

Comment: 'annoying' ..... I especially hate it when the moving target places a different action in the way and you are forced to undo their deed

Comment: This happens with the keyboard on my phone: the suggestion bar shows possible words, and I am about to pick one, but it moves as I type a character, yet my finger was moving toward that spot and the word is now somewhere else. Once a word shows in a suggestion bar, it should either stay there, or get replaced, but not move to a different position. Thank you for the name for this particular aggravation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an appropriate term to use and certainly something you'd want to avoid for any type of frequently-used action. Could you provide a screenshot? It's probably a case of relocating the Send button and/or the word suggestion bar so that one each can appear and disappear without affecting the other's location.

Comment: I don't know how to take screenshots on Android, so :-(

Comment: Here are some [instructions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-take-screenshots-on-android/) if you'd like to give them a try.

Comment: Great, it took some effort, but I got the hang of it. Tomorrow, I'll post the pics.

Comment: @GUIJunkie my older brother is fond of saying, "Tomorrow never comes."

Comment:  I don't even use Swype anymore