# Should 'ABC' keyboard layout be used in single-purpose devices?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have noticed, that some (well, quite many!) single-purpose devices (like: GPS for a car or some photo frames) use 'ABC' keyboard layout as default one, instead of the (local) standard QWERTY. And in some cases, there is not even a setting allowing user to change it.

I think the reason for that is that these devices can be used by people totally unfamiliar with computing. Actually - it's hard for me to find another explanation.

But I believe this group is very small, so the question is: **should it be so? Should the needs of a small group of people shape the user experience of the majority?**

Or maybe my assumptions are wrong and the reason lies somewhere completely else?

Comment: A useful (although not a duplicate) post about uses of ABC keyboards - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33337/hangman-game-on-mobile-qwerty-or-alphabetical-keyboard

Comment: A related question: why do these gadgets use ABC today? What are the manufacturers of these components, and what drives their choice?

Comment: I guess the advantage to a manufacturer in a global market is that they only have to provide the one global layout - as querty isn't a global standard.

Comment: @PhillipW - Well, maybe. But is ABC a global standard? Is it a standard at all? For putting items in an order - maybe. But for input?

Comment: with the export market as it is its easier to use a single ABC than multiple qwertys and azertys variations

Comment: The QWERTY layout has nothing to do with familiarity with computing.  What you might mean is familiarity with "typing".  That layout predates computers by decades.  My understanding of the layout is that it is optimized for touch typing (2 hands and not looking at the keyboard while you type).  You really need to be able to feel the keys on the keyboard for that to work.  With a touch screen, you pretty much have to look at the keyboard to type.  If you're not a touch typist (which a lot of people using a touch screen device might not be), the QWERTY layout is not going to help you.

Comment: At the local train station they have ABC keyboards for ticket destinations. "old folks etc cant use QWERTY keyboards so lets make it usable for them" and totally unusable for the rest of us. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Much of UX is about expectations and recognizing patterns. Anyone who is used to QWERTY will be much faster in finding a specific character in that layout than in an ABC layout because you don't really have to actively think about it. Especially in satnavs, you want to be able to use the keyboard quickly and efficiently, and for a huge part of your user base that means QWERTY.

However, there are some considerations that favor ABC.

There is this issue of internationalization. While we might assume QWERTY would be a decent default in many cases, [entire countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#Variants) use different layouts like AZERTY. Unless you solve this and support whatever layout your user might be used to, it's better to default to a more universal layout like ABC.

I haven't found any evidence, but there are a lot of [claims](http://www.bigkeys.co.uk/plus_technical.asp) that ABC keyboards are easier to use by people suffering from dyslexia. I find that a more logical explanation than people not being used to computers, since computers and keyboards are so ubiqitous anyone will have seen a QWERTY layout before. So, if you want your product to be very inclusive you could opt for ABC as the default, while offering a switch to QWERTY (and AZERTY, etc) for "power users".

Also, QWERTY only works in it's original layout. The keys should be staggered and in 3 lines (Q-P, A-L and Z-M). So, you can't have a layout over 2 or 4 lines and that might be more useful in certain situations than having QWERTY. Take for instance a keyboard layout that has to be navigated using directional keys .

[image]

If the keyboard isn't meant for typing words but just indicating single characters (like in the [hangman examples](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33337/hangman-game-on-mobile-qwerty-or-alphabetical-keyboard?lq=1)), the ABC layout has more flexibility and will probably not affect UX negatively.

Comment: I totally agree with the staggering in 3 lines prerequisity. Regarding dyslexia - this article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslexia states that only 5-10% of people suffer from dyslexia. So my guessing is that (assuming that keys can be arranged in three lines, of course) this should be turned on 'on demand' the same way as accessibility options for vision impaired people. Yet, it is often like this by default, so 90-95% of people potentially suffer from this status quo.

Comment: Having seen a qwerty layout doesn't mean that someone will be comfortable using it.  Many people use improved layouts or country specific ones.

Comment: That's true, but ABC does not address this issue. Actually, the topic of national keyboard layouts is somethind on top of it. In Poland, where I live, there is one keyboard commonly used in computing - QWERTY, with some keys entered with AltGr (e.g. alt+a = ą). Interestingly, we have two modifications of z, which are ż (alt+z) and ź (alt+x), so almost everyone who has used a computer is familiar with this layout. Maybe not everyone who uses GPS has used a computer, but I believe it is a vast majority.

Comment: @JohnGB You're totally right. It really is not just ABC vs QWERTY. "QWERTY" in my answer should read "local standard or anything the user prefers". Which makes me think going for ABC might also be a way to circumvent the i18n issue. If in your country (e.g. Belgium) AZERTY is the standard, perhaps a QWERTY is going to be just as bad as ABC. It's so easy to assume QWERTY as an international standard, but it's not really.

Comment: @KoenLageveen I would argue that being shown a keyboard with keys in an order that you know (assuming you know what alphabetical order is) is better than showing someone a keyboard in an order that they don't know.  I suspect that is why the ABC keyboard is used, but I have no data to back this up.

Comment: Jup, that's true and an angle I didn't originally consider. I'll edit it into my answer. However, I haven't seen any research either.

Comment: I love the example from Apple TV, because one of the main reasons to _retain_ a keyboard layout is to allow typists to leverage their muscle memory for your device. Once there's a layer of abstraction between your fingers and the letters, QWERTY et al are very illogical ways to lay keys out (especially because touch typists can't necessarily remember the precise location of each letter on a keyboard; they do it by "feel").

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following differentiation:

- If the keyboard is for typing (long term and not once in a while) you would want to go with an 'optimized' layout like the QWERTY or something else.
- If the keyboard is not optimized for typing with (both) hands, you can debate about going with ABC keyboard.

eg: Satnav are not necessarily in your hands while typing the address, they might be mounted on the windscreen or fixed in the center console. In both cases user cannot use it with 2 hands to make use of the QWERTY optimization.

eg2: In game consoles, you do not have a QWERTY keyboard (usually) and are given a ABC layout for easier access.

**I would say that ABC might be easier to use while looking and selecting(typing)**.